# Entity Framework Ignore Fields By Convention

Tags: c#, entity-framework, configuration

I'm wondering if it's possible using EF to ignore fields that end with a certain convention.  For example, with the following object:

```
public class Student {
  public long Id { get; set; }

  public int MajorId { get; set; }
  public string MajorName { get; set; }

  public int GenderId { get; set; }
  public string GenderName { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to configure EF to ignore by convention all fields that end with "Name".  The goal is to not have to specify which properties are mapped/unmapped since our objects have many fields, with new ones being added on a somewhat regular basis.

Comment: You can add custom conventions that should do what you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj819164.aspx

Comment: I don't see why you can't just add the `[Ignore]` attribute to it when you add that field. Note that this is bad design: you should have a navigation property of type `Major` and `Gender` which holds the `Id` and `Name`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - can you point me to an article explaining why this is bad design.  Would love to learn from your comment.

Comment: @AdamLevitt: the process I'm talking about is [database normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In essence: you'd be defining the majorid and majorname in every studentrecord. But since those are always the same (the same id always points to the same name), you'd end up with a lot of duplicate values for no reason. That's why these are usually moved to a separate table `Majors` which holds specific information about each `MajorId`. In EF you can then configure this as a single property `public Major Major {get;set;}`.

Comment: No, I wouldn't with this model.  I would not be persisting MajorName. Only the MajorId would be stored in every student record as a foreign key to the Major table.  Once the student is loaded, I'll populate the MajorName field separately with the corresponding text for display purposes.  Your thought is correct, but I think you were just missing context.

Comment: I'm aware that's what you meant to do but you'd be going through hoops to do what is already possible with navigation properties ;) Aka: a property of type `Major` and `Genre`. So I'd advise you to definitely look into doing it like that

Comment: Ok, your approach makes sense.  Is there a way to have a generic class that has the Id/Name as fields that I can map by name? Because otherwise I'd have to create a new Id/Name class for each sub object (major, gender, etc.)

Comment: It's possible but I'm not sure if it's worth the trouble: These types don't really belong together in the type hierarchy so you would only set yourself up for confusion in the future.